# How do we use two 'as..as' pattern together?

Tags: sentence-patterns

What is difference between `as big and as noisy as their car` and `as big and noisy as their car`. Which is more accepted usage among English speakers? How do we use two 'as..as' pattern together.(as big as and as noisy as?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the more common usage would be "as big and noisy" with additional descriptions added as needed. "He was as big and mean and smelly and tough as any mayor I have ever seen."

Additional "as" would not be improper and may be used if one wishes to emphasize each quality.